# Is it useful to monitor framerate over the course of an arbitrary (but long) period of time?

Tags: rendering, game-mechanics, performance, frame-rate, data

How useful is it to keep a measurement of framerate over the course of long times (such as an hour) spanning multiple scenes/data environments?

I've had plenty of times where data throttling/pushing was based on a poll of what's going on in regard to framerate over the course of a minute. I've used ~10 minutes a few times when the game can be sensitive to upcoming high-detail/volume renders to task some unused processing power/memory bandwidth ahead of time.

Anyone come across any situations where long-term polling of frame speed is useful?

Comment: -1 because there doesn't seem to be a specific problem to solve here, it's just a discussion starting question.

Comment: The problem would be 'can I stretch my mind to think of new ways to optimize' especially in areas like this which I would generally ignore.

Comment: Still "no" because you have a presupposed answer in search of a question.

Comment: No idea what you mean. What answer? I still have no idea if anyone has run across a use for this.

Comment: I see a legit question: "Are there any real situtaions, however niche, where developers ... make use of ... frames per hour?" So it had a little fluff in it, and it wasn't the best-phrased question. I wouldn't consider it -1 material.

Comment: As per my conversation with Maik, and having more trouble with this question than I ever anticipated, I went ahead and ran some tests to see what was up. I'm sure the case would be different for different games in different stages but I did actually find a few long-term dips from ~72 to ~55 fps that seemed to be working fine running those stages one at a time. Apparently there's an issue where some resources weren't getting released when I thought they were >_>;; So that's at least one scenario. My engine is still pretty young, probably something that would've been caught with simple testing.

Comment: Tetrad's point is that you have an answer - "frames per hour" - and are looking for the X in question "What's the best units to measure X?". Stack Exchange sites are not good for discussion questions like this, and frankly I think it's a dumb question anyway.

Comment: @Joe: starting to see where the miscommunication may lie. My question though, is not about what I am measuring but rather about the useful of comparing frame render speed over long(er) spans of time.

Comment: Great, then it's about exactly what glowcoder told me it's not about, below. You really should just make a new question, because none of the answers address your (apparently) actual question.

Comment: I'm a bit wary of trying this one again! Dangerous waters.. x_x;

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It may be more useful to create a diagram showing frames per second over a period of time. Ideally this diagram contains annotations about what happened in the world, for example changes of areas, starting and ending of fights.

[image: annotated diagram showing FPS over time]

In the sample diagram it is easy to see that the frame rate is a lot better in the home town than in the dungeon. And there seems to be something very fishy going on in the desert; likely a memory hole.

Comment: Hey good point! That would be a fairly helpful debugging technique in some cases

Comment: I really want to -1 this because it's not an answer to the question at all, but that says volumes more about the question than it does about the quality of the answer.

Comment: While it is not an answer to the title of the question, I am confident that it addresses the first paragraph and the "edit" one of the question posting.

Comment: This graph looks somewhat similar to the test case where I had a drop after zoning to more than 3 areas. Thanks much for the added input and especially +1 for added visual.

Comment: @Joe: I think it's a useful illustration of why a large sampling period is less useful than a small one. If you were measuring over a larger window this same graph would have a much smaller dip in the middle and a slower decline at the end, potentially hiding useful information.

Answer (score 9):

Seems almost as useful as a speed limit saying "2400 km/day" or "614400 km/year". Both are the same as "100 km/hour".

From the mathematical standpoint it makes no difference, but we humans have a narrow perception and we can deal much better with smaller numbers and time-frames.

If you throw 216,000+ FPH at me, I had no idea how long a frame is.

If you tell me 30 frame/s I can calculate without a calculator that 1 frame is 33.3 ms.

So no, I don't think it's a useful measurement, I've never heard somebody using it during several years in game-industry.

**Edit:** Now that I think about it, it would make sense, if 1 frame is very long, like 30 mins, then it is 2 frames/hour, but I doubt the fun factor of that game would be very high ;)
So still "No" for game-industry

Comment: Pretty much in agreement but it is scratching at my mind to find a use for it anyway :) tyvm for input.

Comment: Actually, there is a difference. I can run my car at 120mph, but I can't run it at 2880 miles/day. I have to stop to rest, fuel my car, eat, etc.

Comment: @glowcoder: it doesn't say anything about the duration of your trip. You can drive 2880 miles/day for 10 seconds as well as 120 mph for 2 days. The time you traveled has nothing to do with it, its just the speed.

Comment: Or in other words: you have to rest and fuel your car too if you drive 120 mph for one day, there is no difference, its just a scalar multiplied with both sides of the equation, the underlying information remains the same. 1 mph == 24 mpday, its the same speed.

Comment: @Maik I get your point, but the intent here is not to simply scale fps into fph - the point is to run the simulation/game for an extended period of time to get a view of the long term stability of the frame rate (in exactly the same manner as I described my car. I should note that it doesn't go 120mph anymore, now that I have a wife and kids... :-O  )

Comment: @glowcoder: As Kylotan pointed out, it's impossible to get more information by taking averages over longer periods. A long-term view of framerate stability doesn't benefit from frames-per-hour measurement - I'm not even sure what "a long-term view of framerate stability" means, but I'm pretty sure you're just talking about sampling at two points separated by many hours, which is not at all the same as sampling times between many hours.

Comment: @Joe I'm sorry, but Kylotan is simply mistaken. If every second you count the number of frames since the last time you counted and store that data in an array (which for fph is only 3600 ints/size_of_choice) you can get a view of the frames per hour with a moving window. I am not talking about sampling two points separated by many hours: I'm talking about sampling every second for many hours and graphing the result, bearing in mind you won't get meaningful results until you've gone at least a significant portion (say 5 or 10 minutes)

Comment: "1 mph == 24 mpday, its the same speed" This is true of the average speed, but not the actual speed. I realize I confused the point by originally expressing thoughts about 216,000 fph. That's just the goal I am aiming for the combined fps without every dropping below 42.. Again, the question is actually meant to be about the **exact time difference over an hour**. Not the average.

Answer (score 5):

Frames per hour is an okay measurement if you're making a render farm or some other non-realtime rendering system. (A better measurement would be hours/hour though.)

Frames per second is not particularly useful either, and most developers that are any good at optimization will look at ms/frame instead, even if they still describe targets as X fps.

This question seems a bit artificial because I've never seen anyone actually describing measurements as such though.

Comment: FPH is definitely artificial, just looking to see if anyone has ever dealt with it or any longer-term measuring of framerate in any form. Given ms/frame is more precise, but I deal with avg fps over a few minutes pretty often to calibrate throughput.

Answer (score 2):

No, there's no use for frames per hour, in a system that requires multiple frames per second. it would be like measuring speed in millimetres per hour or something.

Even if you did have a situation where you want to look forward 10 minutes (why?!) to predict some slowdown event, any problem will manifest itself as a sharp negative spike in the frame rate at that point. By merging that freak event into the more normal rendering 5 minutes either side of it and looking at the 10 minute aggregate, you actually make it harder to spot these problems, not easier.

Mathematically speaking, taking the average of a set of samples effectively applies a low-pass filter to the data, leaving you with less information than you started with. The larger the set of samples, the more the filter cuts out. Since there's nothing you can do with less information that can't be done with more information, there's no use for this value.

Comment: In response to "(why?!)": because there was an FMV coming up that had alot of dynamic parts to it. We usually had advanced notice through the scripting and quest engines that there would be some heavy rendering coming up while, at the same time, the player is about to go through a fair number of dialog-driven changes to said FMV during which we prerendered parts of the video.

Answer (score 1):

FPH? I had no idea what that meant till I clicked on this question.

And **no** I cannot see what could be useful about knowing how many frames per hour.

What would be useful is logging the frames per second over time to make a visual graph, or to analyze programmatically.

With frames per hour, you could have 60fps most of the time, and every 20 seconds 1fps, and the final reading wont look different than a solid fps that is lower than 60.

Comment: Good point, this is really what I'm talking about - will reword it somewhat.

Comment: FPS looks bad on a graph because it's an inverse of what we actually optimize, which is ms/frame.

Comment: @Joe I don't know about you, but I optimize for user experience. I'd rather have a slower framerate that doesn't get noticed by the user (which you can do with blurs and other tricks) than a faster framerate but still not fast enough to be missed by most users' eyes.

Comment: @glowcoder: I have no idea how that's relevant to your poor choice of units.

Comment: @Joe I don't know how to say this without sounding rude, so please don't take it as such. You don't see the relevance of the metric. I get that. I **do** see the relevance of the metric, and have used it effectively in the past. I'm sorry that you don't understand how I was able to do so, even though I've attempted to explain it. I take the blame for apparently not explaining it clearly enough to be understood. Now, the above comment was only in direct response to your claim of "what we actually optimize". That's all. It wasn't directly related to any other aspect of this post/thread.

Comment: No, I don't see the relevance of your claim that "optimizing for user experience" is bettered by FPH. Regardless of the units, one can use tricks like motion blur or locking framerates for stability to get a better experience at low framerates. But your measurement methodology is garbage, and if you don't understand what I mean when i saw "ms/frame is what we actual optimize", I don't think you're on the road to fixing it either.

Comment: The two claims are completely independent of each other. My claim of "I optimize for user experience" and "fph can be valid" are two entirely separate comments.

Answer (score 0):

Quite a few years ago, when professional vehicle simulators were *very* expensive, I heard about a vessel simulator (e.g oil tanker type of vessel) which had a frame rate of 2 frames/second.

In *that* context a 120 frames/hour metric would be meaningful, perhaps even more useful compared to 2 frames/second, especially if you have reason to believe that those two numbers are not exact but something that has been estimated.

Assume the scenario that those numbers (120 and 2) are based on some values that are rounded to 120 or 2 respectively.  In the case of 2, you could expect the frame rate to vary quite a lot, anywhere from 1.5 to 2.5 frames per second.  In the case of 120, the frame rate could vary from 115 to 125 frames per hour, which is a bit more accurate.

But again, quite a hypothetical kind of simulator software these days.

Comment: Except it's 120 frames/minute, not 120 frames/hour. In this case I'd want seconds/frame anyway.

Comment: You are right, it would be 7200 frames hour.  Mea culpa. (Someone should downvote my answer... it's that stupid!)

Answer (score -2):

There are times when it is necessary, for "serious" applications, such as real-life Flight Simulators.

*EDIT*: In a flight simulator environment, such as the ones used to train pilots in routine and adverse situations, it is entirely possible that the simulator knows what scenario is coming up, and would need to pre-plan out possible responses the pilot may make, which may include abrupt changes in altitude (height), attitude (roll and pitch), direction (yaw), all of which may quickly change the upcoming scenery.  The simulator plans for this by preloading the data and precomputing visibility in the potential upcoming scenes.

The long-term polling of frame-rate is necessary to help ensure that the training was a valid experience for the pilot.  If the frame-rate had dipped below an acceptable level, then the training regimen may not qualify for FAA (re)certification of pilot readiness.

Comment: Why? They have similar requirements on the frame-rate like any other game, "serious" or not. What is the advantage of saying my heart beat is **3600 beats per hour** over **60 beats per minute**?

Comment: Can you expand on this at all? Would be very interested to understand the applications for flight simulators.

Comment: @Maik: still holding that it doesn't seem particularly relevant to go for an hour but when reading different amounts of time (say 60 fps vs 3600 fps) it can be useful to see the differences in the distribution. i,e.. which seconds have + or - 60fps during that minute can be indicative of places you can get a little extra performance or bottlenecks that need to be avoided.

Comment: If you measure the frame-rate for an hour or for a day or for a minute, it makes no difference if you measure it in frames/sec or frames/hour. It's just the frequency, it says nothing about the resolution or the sample-rate or the duration, you just multiply both sides of the equation with a scalar, the underlying data remains the same.

Maybe this makes it clearer:
**When you say my car drives 100km/hour, it doesn't mean you are driving for 1 hour. It says nothing about the total time you traveled, its just the speed.**

Comment: @Maik: yes i botched the phrasing up fairly well in this question, trying to rectify that. apologies. I'm really saying that in general measuring framerate over a given, continuous execution tends to become irrelevant after a short time. Are there times I really need to keep the longer run in mind?

Comment: @Garet: I'm not sure I can follow you there. Usually the contract with the publisher says that the game must have a frame-rate of X Frames per second at all times. So you must measure it at all times, long or short run doesn't matter. Are you thinking about tools how to observe your frame-rate better than the usual average-frame-rate? Is the question about that? If yes, then use min/max and more importantly [Standard-Deviation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation), that gives you more precise information about the distribution of your frame-rate than a simple average.

Comment: Alright, well currently I can run a helper that will fairly accurately keep track of framerate per second without (hardly) altering the results at all. If desired, I could have the time of each frame within a one hour period graphed by distance (in time) between frames. I'm just unsure if I can get anything more useful from this than the same data over at most 10 minutes. I may just go ahead and see if I notice anything.

Comment: Did you have a look at the [Standard Deviation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation)? It gives you much more information than the Average. You can visualize a graph then showing how many percent of the frames are in +/- 1ms, how many percent in +/- 5ms etc. The normal average tends to _hide_ frame-glitches as long as they are equally distributed, they equalize each other, i.e. {20ms, 30ms, 40ms} gives an average frame-time of 30ms, you don't see the problem cases, the Standard-Deviation helps you find them anyway.

Comment: I do use standard deviation where applicable, or at least I think so :) I'm not quite sure how it comes into play here, since I'm not talking averages either. I'm talking about 216,000 straight measures of time difference. Zoomed out to the whole hour sure, I can't really notice the smaller differences but I tweaked the report to color code the line where there's any *actual* deviation of 20% or more within a given 5 second interval. I did find something slightly useful at least.

Comment: Due to the down-votes, I won't be participating in this community, which could be a shame, since I actually know of what I speak.

Comment: @Andy: unfortunate to hear, I would still be very interested to know how you used this in flight simulations.

Answer (score -2):

Frames per hour says a lot more about your environment. It is a keen indicator for the long-term enjoyability of the game.

For example, you may have 50fps in some parts of the game, but in crowded areas, or areas of high intensity graphics or physics, you drop to 10 or 12.

If you graph the fph over the course of the game, you have a general idea of where you're at. It's no substitute for knowing that the frame rate drops in some circumstances, but if you're consistantly only at 15 or 20 fph you know there's a problem. The game should be high fps MOST of the time, if not ALL of the time. So having a moving average of the the long-term fps can help you achieve that goal.

Comment: That being said, you mentioned "the only use is for benchmarking." Well, in a sense yes. The only use for metrics on your frame-rate (no matter the unit) is for analysis on the performance of the program.

Comment: This doesn't work anyway - graphing FPH gives the same results without losing sudden drops in the FPS. And if you want variance, just graph variance. (Or its more well-known square root, standard deviation.)

Comment: @Joe I've used it as a metric in the past for games (and other simulators) and it's been quite effective. I actually used the metric of 10 minutes instead of an hour, but the philosophy is the same. I didn't need anything fancy - just noticing that the "average fps" was only 18-20 indicated there was an issue in the general case, not the specific case. We did some refactoring and increased it to about 30. We never would have had that without the fph-stype metric.

Comment: -1 because FPH == 3600 * FPS, its simply the same information, only scaled by a higher number. The implication that it has anything to do with a long run or not or that it shows any additional information is simply a wrong understanding of what frequency means.

Comment: @Maik not only do you not understand this, you don't understand algebra. It is NOT simply fps*3600. Why? Because the fps changes over time. It is (average fps) * 3600. Yes, that's correct. But that's the main point - AVERAGE fps over time. But to simply say FPH = FPS * 3600 is entirely missing the point of FPH.